# Recover IDE partition in windows xp

Tags: windows, partitioning, ntfs, partition-recovery

I have accidentally delete my partition (Right click to My computer --> Manage). Now when i run some recovery tool, it show me every thing is there.

As i have not formatted the disk or partition so as of my knowledge that the drives entry from partition Table is deleted only. How can i get that entry to get back my drive in normal form

OS : Microsoft XP
File System : NTFS

Comment: Which recovery tool did you run?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org) to easily [recover the partition](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step#Partition_table_recovery). It is a common data recovery software. It has a [Windows version](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download) alternatively you can get it on a linux live  cd.

Once you install it, all you have to do it search for all partitions, and once it finds your missing one, write the table.

Comment: It would be good to take [MBR backup](http://www.ghacks.net/2010/09/01/how-to-backup-and-restore-the-mbr-in-windows/) first...